# How do you read an exchange rate?

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency

I came across these sentences when reading about the [J-Curve Effect](https://saylordotorg.github.io/text_international-economics-theory-and-policy/s22-12-the-j-curve-effect.html):

> In the goods market model, it is assumed that the exchange rate (E<sub>$/£</sub>) is directly related to current account demand in the United States. The logic of the relationship goes as follows. **If the dollar depreciates, meaning E<sub>$/£</sub> rises**, then foreign goods will become more expensive to U.S. residents, causing a decrease in import demand.

I don't understand this sentence: "If the dollar depreciates, meaning E<sub>$/£</sub> rises..."

Doesn't E<sub>$/£</sub> mean that the dollar is the base currency? So for example, if I said that E<sub>$/£</sub> = £1.12 then with one dollar you get 1.12 pounds? Doesn't this mean that if the dollar depreciates, then the exchange rate should decrease?

So in the case of depreciation of the dollar, the paragraph says that it means that E<sub>$/£</sub> rises. But how is that possible?

If the E<sub>$/£</sub> is £1.12 as of now , and say, it becomes E<sub>$/£</sub> = £1.15. Before, with one dollar you could buy £1.12, but now you can buy more (£1.15). This means that the dollar has appreciated in value.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Dollars per pound is measured in... dollars. ( $/£ means a variable amount of dollars, for 1 pound) So your E$/£ is given in dollars, so your argument is upside down.

Comment: Im sorry i cant seem to wrap my head around it... on investopedia it states : A standard currency quote lists two currencies as a rate. For example, USD/JPY = 104.08. The first of the two currencies (USD) is the base currency and represents a single unit, or the number 1 in the case of a fraction such as 1/104.08. The second is the quoted currency and is represented by the rate as the amount of that currency needed to equal one unit of the base currency. The way this quote reads is: One U.S. dollar buys 104.08 units of Japanese yen.

Comment: Yes, so that would be 104.08 **yens per dollar**. The dollars per yen would be in the 0.01 range.

Comment: So in our case, it would read that one US dollar buys 1.12 pounds. How is my argument wrong? If the exchange rate was £/$, then one pound would buy a certain amount of dollars

Comment: then it would mean that 1 dollar buys 104.08 yen . so this implies that my us dollar in my example would buy 1.12 pounds. so if the exhcange rate appreciates, my dollar would now buy 1.15 pounds. So the dollar appreciates.

Comment: All these arguments make it seem as if dollars per pound is measured in... pounds. (

Comment: No, you need to read that 1.12 dollars buys one pound. And that would make the rest of the sentence correct as well. Might be that the author of the original sentence did it wrong, but it all parses well if you assume that 1.12 dollars buys 1 pound

Comment: but how is it possible if the dollar is the base year?

Comment: i always studies how the first currency is the base year.

Comment: i believe thaat the author is wrong at this point, since the example of the yen is the opposite.

Comment: If 1.12 dollars buys one pound , then the exchange rate should be £/$ and NOT $/£. please confirm that this is right

Comment: @GGGG To my surprise, that is correct.  If you search google for "dollar/pound", it will show an exchange rate of 0.78.  1 USD buys 0.78 GBP.

Comment: What does this mean ? That my thinking is corrrect? I am having trouble understanding if for example i had an exchange rate of £/$=1.10, does this mean that the 1.10 is expressed in terms of dollars or pounds?

Comment: meaning that £/$=1.10$ or 1.10£?

Comment: Please provide a link to the source article, or provide context on what `E$` represents.

Comment: https://saylordotorg.github.io/text_international-finance-theory-and-policy/s11-12-the-j-curve-effect.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calcuate forward exchange rate or interest rate parity?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/49763/how-to-calcuate-forward-exchange-rate-or-interest-rate-parity)