# How to properly understand an exchange rate

Tags: investing, foreign-exchange, currency

I am having an enormous amount of confusion on exchange rates.

If for example , i have an exchange rate of £/$=1.10, i know that with one pound i can buy 1.10 dollars. **First question**: So can the exchange rate be written as 1.10$?.

Now, in terms of appreciation and depreciation:

lets say that the exchange rate increases to £/$=1.20.

On investopedia i read that:  As a rule of thumb, the increase or decrease of a rate always corresponds to the appreciation/depreciation of the base currency, and the inverse corresponds to the quoted currency.

So according to investopedia, the pound has appreciated.

But then i read another article that states:

if you have an exchange rate quoted as X/Y,

If X/Y goes up then Y appreciated..

If X/Y goes down then Y depreciated..

Then according to this article, the dollar has appreciated.

Can somebody tell me in simple terms how to understand what currency is appreciating/depreciating ? And can somebody please answer my first question?

EDIT: this is not a dupe. I am trying to understand how to read exchange rates and why two articles give opposing answers on the same topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you read an exchange rate?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/117263/how-do-you-read-an-exchange-rate)

Comment: No, these are two different questions that i asked.

Comment: Can you share the articles that conflict?

Comment: https://www.analystforum.com/forums/cfa-forums/cfa-level-iii-forum/91272265

Comment: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/currency-appreciation.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look further down the [second thread](https://www.analystforum.com/forums/cfa-forums/cfa-level-iii-forum/91272265) you link to, it says:

> CFA Institute’s convention is USD/GBP 1.5253 means $1.5253 = £1.0.

This is **not** the standard convention. Your first link does use the standard convention, which is why they seem to give contradictory results.

Comment: Thanks! Greatly appreciate it. I may have another question : if , for example, In 1999, the euro was valued at $1.18, and on On June 16, 2016, it was valued at $1.1132, then the Euro has depreciated and the USD has appreciated. Then can i write the exhange rate for 1999 as EUR/USD=1.18? Or should i right it as EUR/USD=1.18$? (meaning should i add the dollar sign at the end).

Comment: No dollar sign needed. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_pair) gives a decent overview of the syntax.

Comment: But then its right to say that the exchange rate is EUR/USD and not USD/EUR, correct?

Comment: That is correct.